# Modal View Controller loading with black background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have seen a few of these issues by searching but mostly relating to storyboards.

I am simply pragmatically creating a modal view controller. It is actually for the use with reachability, once the connection is seen as NotReachable I present a modal view controller like this:

```
-(void)checkConnection: (Reachability*) curReach {
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [curReach currentReachabilityStatus];
        if (netStatus == NotReachable) {
            NSLog(@"inernet reach - not reachable");

            UIViewController *modalViewController = [[MESConnectionModalViewController alloc] init];
            modalViewController.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2f];
            modalViewController.view.opaque= YES;
            [self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:modalViewController animated:YES];

}
}
```

Within the view controller `MESConnectionModalViewController` there is currently no code, just the standard.

When the modal view is being transitioned onto the current view the background looks correct (this is for a brief second or two). Once the modal is completely over screen it is full black, instead of being partly black. I am looking to basically slightly cover the current content. The above code is seutp in the app delegate and called whenever Reachability updates so I am trying to show a modal view controller whilst the internet connection is being resolved.

Comment: Are trying to set the modal view to be smaller than the view itself? If so why not use cg rect and set coordinates to it so when it is presented it would be smaller than the view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modal views didn't support transparency (for iPhone).
But you can add 'UIView' to parent view and animate it using `CoreAnimation`

**EDIT**

```
-(void)checkConnection: (Reachability*) curReach {
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [curReach currentReachabilityStatus];
    if (netStatus == NotReachable) {
        NSLog(@"internet reach - not reachable");
        UIViewController *modalViewController = [[MESConnectionModalViewController alloc] init];
        //Set y position to animate it
        CGRect frame = modalViewController.view.frame;
        frame.origin.y = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].frame.size.height;
        modalViewController.view.frame = frame;
        modalViewController.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2f];
        [self.view addSubview:modalViewController.view];
        //Animate appearing
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
            modalViewController.view.frame = frame;
        }];
    }
}
```

Also you can store `modalViewController` as property to acces to it in future.

Comment: Could you explain how to do this please? As a little more background this is used as a message to the user anywhere through out the application, so setup in app delegate when connection to the internet is lost.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I get two errors. [self.view line... property view not found on app delegate. This is because I cannot add a view to the app delegate i need to add it to the presented view controller (whichever is currently shown), but I am unsure how to do this? Secondly, the error on frame.y line... no member named y on struct CGRect?

Comment: Edited second issue. You can try to add subview to `UIWindow`. [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:modalViewController.view];

Comment: Thanks, this works but i have an issue where if the application is started (from fresh) and no internet connection is available it does not show. I think the issue is that the view above is displayed before the actual main view is loaded. Is there anyway I can sort this, would you say this should be a new question?

Comment: Also, how do I check if this view is being presented and remove this subview if connection is restored?

Comment: Store `modalViewController` as property and when connection is present call `[modalViewController.view removeFromSuperview]`. Don't forget if answer helps you accept it and vote =)

Comment: I will ;) Ill put the other issue as another QU. EDIT the other issue is resolved too :-)

Answer (score 1):

what you need is a second `UIWindow` in `AppDelegate` class
you can make something like UIAlertView on top of everything!
believe me that's what you need, and make sure to set

```
myWindow2.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert;
```

to access your window (get the pointer):

```
UIWindow *myWindow2 = [(AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate myWindow2];
```

Comment: Could you provide a little more information on what needs to be completed? Should I subclass UIAlertView and change the viewDidLoad to include the colour scheme for the view? Then how is this presented?

Comment: for alerts your options are iOS default alerts (UIAlertView or UIActionSheet) OR create your own:  1-add a window to AppDelegate and set its level to alert level. 2- add your custom alert, which is a UIView base class that has a title label, text label and some buttons, then use window.hidden = [YES/NO] to show your alert!